# Add apostrophes in driver.get()

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hellow I long time search solve for this problem:

I have this code:

```
    link_of_item = input('Please past here the link of item from newegg:\n')

    driver.get(link_of_item)

    print('name of item: ',driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/h1').text)
    print('Price of item now is: ',driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/strong').text)
    price = input("write the price you want get: ")
```

I need add ' ' to link_of_itm For it to be like this:

```
driver.get('link_of_item')
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that? The return value of `input(...)` is already a string.

Comment: I must add ' ' to link_of_item because without ' '  it not run in driver.get
If I put manual link with ' ' it is work

Comment: What does "not run" mean? You need to show us the full error and traceback.

Comment: `driver.get('\'' + link_of_item + '\'')` you can do it like this.

Comment: @Dev ty that help me :)